# Connecting ELK(Logstash) to Zabbix via Plugin

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, zabbix

I am trying to configure Logstash to send any error logs to a remote Zabbix server.

I have got my inputs and filters working fine and the if statement is correctly outputting to the file log however I am not sure how to get the Output to correctly send to Zabbix.

I am not sure if it's my configuration here or on the ELK server or the Zabbix Server or else communication in between.

I have zero experience with Zabbix however I've set up a trapper which I belive should collect the log message coming from the ELK server

[image]

```
input {
        file{
            path=>["/opt/logstash/alectronic_test_input.log"]
        }
}

filter {
  # Filter out empty lines in the audit logs
  if ([message] =~ /^[\s]*$/) {
      drop {}
  }

//some other filter stuff which breaks up fields which will have a field called "LogLvl"

if [LogLvl]=="ERROR" {
        mutate{
                add_field => {
                        "sendToZabbix"=>"true"
                }
        }
}else{
        mutate{
                add_field => {
                        "sendToZabbix"=>"false"
                }
        }
}

if [sendToZabbix]=="true"{
        mutate{
                add_field =>{
                        "whereAmIGoing"=>"ToZabbix"
                        "zhost"=>"jenkins"
                        "zkey"=>"trap"
                }
        }
}

}

output {
if[sendToZabbix]=="true"{
        file{
                path => "/opt/logstash/alectronic_test_output.log"
        }
        zabbix{
                zabbix_host=>"zhost"
                zabbix_server_host=>"zabbix.alectronic.co"
                #zabbix_server_port=>10051
                #zabbix_key=>"zkey"
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I seem to have had was that I was using the wrong Zabbix_Server_Host Address (apparently the system I was using had a public facing IP and private facing IP).